# Publish over ssh Jenkins doesn't communicate with ansible

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible

I am new to docker and ansible. I have jenkins running into a docker container and ansible in an external vm. I installed the plugin publish over ssh in jenkins and it doesn't communicate with ansible. Jenkins container ip address: 172.18.x x Ansible ip address: 192.168.x.x

The ping from jenkins container to ansible ssh server us successful, while the other way around it's not possible. Could it be a network issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose the port of jenkins container so that your ansible will be able to reach your jenkins. I think you are trying to reach using default port 8080 if not feel free to change the port.

`docker run -p localhost:8080:8080`

Syntax:
`docker run -p localhost:<external-port>:<internal-port>`

Here the port 8080 will be the port exposed to the ansible to reach your jenkins. But port 8080 is the port inside the container which is serving jenkins, to reach it from outside(ansible) you are exposing the port 8080.

Now you can reach your jenkins continer from your :8080

Comment: It still doesn't work and this is the message I get: jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [Ansible]. Message [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]]